# Spring Schema Registry Server and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to run Spring Cloud Schema Registry Server as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_schema_registry_server). I want schemas to persist between restart, so I want to use MySQL for that. But I got the following error during application start: `Table 'sr.schema_repository' doesn't exist`.

Does this mean I have to create the required table myself? But what is the structure of this table? And how come that when using default embedded H2 database the needed table is created automatically?

Answer (score 0):

To setup SpringSchemaRegistry with an external Database you need to do the following steps

## 1. Step: Add Database-Driver

As a first step, you need to add the database JDBC driver to your module (gradle / maven).

## 2. Step: Add datasource configuration to your `application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/schema-registry
    username: schema-registry
    password: schema-registry
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
```

## 3. Step: Create tables

You can setup hibernate `ddl-auto` so that the tables are created and updated automatically on every startup. Therefore add the following to your application.yml file.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Note: `ddl-auto: update` will create the tables automatically and update them on every startup, when something with the JPA entities changes (or maybe your naming strategies).

If you prefer, there is only one table required. You can easily create it with the following SQL script.

```
CREATE TABLE `schema_repository` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `definition` longtext NOT NULL,
  `format` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

That script is for MySQL, but the structure is quite simple so you easily adapt it to your preferred database.